# Array is still empty even after being set in DispatchQueue.main.async Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

**Edit: re-worded because array isn't nil, but it doesn't have any values set and it should **

Here's the code: 
      var calendarArray: [Feed] = []

```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.calendarArray = self.dataFetcher.getRSSFeed(withURL: NSLocalizedString("CALENDAR", comment: ""), andIsAnEvent: false) as! [Feed]
    }

    let customNib = UINib(nibName: "UpcomingDatesCustomCell", bundle: nil)
    datesTableView.register(customNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "upcomingDatesCustomCell")
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.datesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "upcomingDatesCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! UpcomingDatesCustomCell

    // update ui based off what's stored in calendarArray

    return cell
  }
```

This is happening in awakeFromNib.

When `calendarArray` is accessed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it is out of bounds...

What's happening here?

Note: I'm running async on a main thread because this is pulling something from online and we have a loading spinner.

Comment: There's no context here. Show a bit more relevant code. Also confirm that this code is actually being called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @rmaddy added the rest of file

Comment: Most likely you have a bug in your `getRSSFeed` method that returns far too soon.

Comment: @rmaddy Does it make a difference that this works without the `DispatchQueue.main.async` surrounding it? But when that line is added it sets to `nil`. I just started learning about GCD today, so I'm very new.

Comment: @MirekE actually, it's not nil, but it isn't holding any values. It does hold values when it's not wrapped in this async {}.

Comment: Put a print statement at the end of the closure and into `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to ensure that the asynchronous code returns before the variable is used.

Comment: @MirekE looks like the closure is not being called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Bingo. Put `tableView.reloadData` to the end of the closure... I would also put the asynchronous code to `viewDIdLoad`

Comment: Is your `dataFetcher.getRSSFeed()` method running in a background thread?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't return 4 from `numberOfRowsInSection`. This method seems to get called before `calendarArray` has any items, and thus you have your out of bounds error. Why did you choose 4 specifically? If you're trying to display all the items in `calendarArray`, then use:

```
return calendarArray.count
```

Also, you should probably not populate your array with data in this way. I'm making assumptions here, but it seems like your `dataFetcher.getRSSFeed` method does a synchronous network request because you've wrapped it in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`. This will not have the effect you want. By dispatching in this way, you're effectively skipping one run loop, then running your code on the main thread anyway. You should either dispatch to a background thread (not the main thread) and do you fetch there

**OR**

You should really consider using `NSURLSession` to make a asynchronous requests. Fetching data synchronously is not a good idea in iOS for a number of reasons.

EDIT: Additional info

Comment: What's happening here is this is the code for a widget on the home screen of my university's app. The widget shows the next 4 upcoming dates. So I know there will be 4 rows no matter what.

Comment: Oops..I thought I was adding a line break and not submitting my comment, sorry. I'll look into what the getRSSFeed method does, but its setup like I have it in other places in the app, I believe, where it works.

Comment: then you should return the smaller of the two numbers. If you always return 4, then there could be cases where an array with fewer objects can crash your app. Something like: `return min(calendarArray.count, 4)`

Comment: The `NSURLSession` comment is just a bit of advice. Sometimes "it works" and "best practice" are not the same thing.

Comment: I never thought of that about the return smallest number! Great idea. I'll read up on some of this stuff you've recommended tomorrow after sleeping. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jped If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it so that others can benefit in the future.

Comment: I didnt get to work on this today, I should be able to either tomorrow or Tuesday

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.calendarArray = self.dataFetcher.getRSSFeed(withURL: NSLocalizedString("CALENDAR", comment: ""), andIsAnEvent: false) as! [Feed]
}
```

doesn't make sense. You are telling the compiler that:"First get me the main thread, then fetch the data in a background thread!!!", which obviously is not gonna update the array or UI.

This is what you should do when doing multi-threading:

```
DispatchQueue.global(attributes: [.qosDefault]).async { 
    // fetch data here  
    let contents = self.dataFetcher.getRSSFeed(withURL: NSLocalizedString("CALENDAR", comment: ""), andIsAnEvent: false)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
    // UI Updates
    self.calendarArray = contents
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Also, as @daltonclaybrook suggested, you should also return `calendarArray.count` in your `numberOfRowsInSection`

And I do recommend you put this inside `viewDidLoad` rather than `awakeFromNib`

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, my array still has 0 values when it reaches `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But when I use: ` calendarArray = self.dataFetcher.getRSSFeed(withURL: NSLocalizedString("CALENDAR", comment: ""), andIsAnEvent: false) as! [Feed]` on its own outside of any GCD curly braces it works fine. Also, I can't use `viewDidLoad` because we're loading from .xib not storyboards...unless you can do that which I'm not sure of

Comment: @jped You CAN use viewDidLoad with xib. And, is your getRSSFeed() method running in the background? If so, you are going to need to modify it in your DataFetcher class, and use a completion block to notify the compiler when the background fetching is completed.

Comment: here is the line from the .m file of DataFetcher class right before the implementation, I don't believe this is running in the background but it does seem to be using a completion block: `[[DataManager sharedInstance] fetchURLSynchronously:urlPath withFinishBlock:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {`